# OnChange event function

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have the next three input's :

```
<input type="file" name="first"/>
<input type="file" name="second"/>
<input type="file" name="third"/>
```

And I want to do something if the file is chosen. I have next function :

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="INPUT-NAME"]').change(function (){
       alert("Selected");
    });
});
```

Is there any way to pass a `name` of the clicked input field to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`$(this).attr('name')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method or just **[`this.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name)** for getting the `name` attribute

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    alert("Selected" + this.name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="first" />
<input type="file" name="second" />
<input type="file" name="third" />
```

Comment: @Boky : glad to help :)